# FormBuilder in ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, symfony, formbuilder

I've got a simple question. 
In Symfony 2 your able to use the formbuilder to create forms, see this link for more info http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html.

Does ASP .NET MVC 4 has something like this?

Comment: What specifically does that tool do?  In Visual Studio you can generate simple views and controllers for create/edit/delete actions based on the model.

Comment: This probably would help you: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using forms in Asp .Net mvc 4 :

@using (Html.BeginForm())

{

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

}

Here is a basic tutorial on how to use Forms and also about MVC :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-view-controller-Step-by-Step-in-7#Step2:-%20Creating%20the%20input%20HTML%20form%20using%20helper%20classes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here's a basic example (for action "ActionName", controller "ControllerName" and model's property "PropertyName"):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName")
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.PropertyName);
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.PropertyName);
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.PropertyName);
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

There are other Html Helpers like TextBoxFor for different inputs. They all start with prefix @Html.